# Modify Disabled Button mouse cursor in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I have a VB.net application and need to modify the mouse cursor when hovers over a disabled button from 'hand' to 'nodrop'. Can anyone provide a code sample?

Comment: I think just `Button1.Cursor = System.Windows.Forms.Cursors.No`

Comment: That cannot work, a disabled button stops responding to *all* input.  So it ignores any mouse messages, including the ones that make the Cursor property effective.  Proper UI is to make the button *look* disabled, it does by default.  The user doesn't need any additional UI cues.

Comment: Just disabling the button should work, however, existing CSS make the disabled look not too distinctive and users get frustrated trying to click on it before realizing it's disabled (cannot refactor the CSS without significant effort). The 'dummy' disabled idea will work but it is a work around, not a real solution. I may go with this if no better solution is found.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean no drop?

```
Private Sub Button1_MouseHover(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.MouseHover
    Button1.Cursor = System.Windows.Forms.Cursors.No
End Sub
```

I am guessing you mean when someone drags a item over? Take a look at all the button events you will likely see one that fits what you require.

Comment: Not dragging but rather mouse over. The NoDrop is the 'No Entry' icon used frequently to indicate object hovered over cannot be used.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply but I updated it. You have to use the mouse hover event. Also note that the button will still be functional if clicked unless you disable it